# How would I search a JSON array in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I've got an JSON Array listed below:

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "6125496b64ec43ef984a48ad",
      "imdb_id": "tt10872600",
      "name": "Spider-Man: No Way Home",
      "type": "movie",
      "year": "2021"
    },
    {
      "_id": "61f3e33b64ec43ef98553e07",
      "imdb_id": "tt13634480",
      "name": "The Ice Age Adventures of Buck Wild",
      "type": "movie",
      "year": "2022"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c4f384dd582b25756275494",
      "imdb_id": "tt9032400",
      "name": "Eternals",
      "type": "movie",
      "year": "2021"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm wanting to make a function to search through this array by `imdb_id` or `name` (not both).
How would I go about doing this?

My poor attempt:

```js
const json = require('./test.json');
function Search(file){
  for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    console.log(file[i].results[i].imdb_id);
  }
}
Search(json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At simplest, you could leverage the inbuilt filtering function, something like this

```
const idOrNameEquals = searchStr => item => item.imdb_id === searchStr || item.name === searchStr

const json = require('./test.json')
const foundItems = json.result.filter(idOrNameEquals('Eternals'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try using filter

```
function SearchJson(json, imdb_id, name){
  return json.result.filter( function(item) {
    return   imdb_id==null?  item.name == name : item.imdb_id==imdb_id
  });
};
```

test

```
 var result= SearchJson(json,null, "Eternals");
```

result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c4f384dd582b25756275494",
    "imdb_id": "tt9032400",
    "name": "Eternals",
    "type": "movie",
    "year": "2021"
  }
]
```